# Why it does't work when I click the delete button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Here is the first part of my project:

```
<div id="div_water" style="display: none" align="center">  
    <table width="100%" border="0" id="printTbl" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" class="table">
        <tr class="TR_BG_list" id="printsizescroll" style="display:none">
            <td align="right" class="list_link" style="width: 214px">
            Resize the pictrue：
            </td>
            <td align="left" class="list_link">
                Description:
            <asp:TextBox ID="PrintSizeDec" runat="server" CssClass="form"  style="width: 106px"/>
             width|height:
            <asp:TextBox ID="PrintSmallSize" runat="server" CssClass="form"  style="width: 50px"/>
    &nbsp;
            <label>
                 <input type="button" name="PintSizeAddClick" value="Add" class="form" id="ButtonAdd" style="width: 44px" onclick="createInputTexts(this)" />
            </label>
           <span class="helpstyle" style="cursor: help;" title="Click to get some help" onclick="Help('H_WaterParam_0008',this)">Help</span>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="TR_BG_list">
    <td align="center" colspan="2" class="list_link">
        <label>
        <input type="submit" name="Savewater" value=" Submit " class="form" id="Savewater" runat="server" onserverclick="Savewater_ServerClick" />
        </label>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label>
        <input type="reset" name="Clearwater" value=" Reset " class="form" id="Clearwater" runat="server" />
        </label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The second: the event handler of the button:

```
function createInputTexts() {

    var trOrigin = $("#printsizescroll");
    var trClone = trOrigin.clone(true);
    var target = $("#printTbl tr:last-child").prev();
    trClone.find(":button").val("Delete").bind("click", function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
    });
    trClone.css('display', '');
    // Here you can also set new ID.
    target.after(trClone);
}
```

When I click the delete button, it doesn't work, why did it act in that way?
I have try to do it by replace the bind() method by click() which is the shotcut of the bind() method,but I am sorry to find that it still failed.

Comment: Well, in javascript it looks you spelled delete wrong.

Comment: yep, I did spelled wrong, but it is just the value in the button,has nothing to do with my question.I can give it any name I want

Comment: post more markup.. to make clear..

Comment: I have re-edit my question now, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try with delegate event handler like **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)**

```
$('#printTbl').on('click','input[type=button][value=Delte]', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
});
```

This will bind `click` event to all `button`s with `value=Delte` that append to DOM dynamically. You not need to bind within loop.

#### Note

check that is it `Delte` of `Delete`

Comment: When I try your way, it just delete the whole table, so it isn't what I want. The button of the first row is used as the add button and the rests are delete button.

Comment: @JacobChen can you post your whole markup, I need to see markup to change your `remove()` code within `click`, event binding is just fine

Comment: I have made some change ,see again